# How to know if a Neo4j background job completed successfully?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm using Neo4j. For large data imports from external csvs, parquets, etc. there is a very handful command for "fire and forget", the `apoc.periodic.submit`. There is also the `apoc.periodic.list` that list the background jobs.

During the execution of the background job it appears in the output of `apoc.periodic.list`. But after it finishes, either by an error or by a successful execution, it will disappear from this list without any feedback from the completion status.

Is there a general way to check if a background job finish status? Is there a more suitable API for my purposes?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a way to directly check error status on the fire&forget routines, I don't see it in the documentation (they are fire&forget, so it comes with the territory?)

Ideas

- don't background the query itself, background a process/task that waits for a blocking Cypher execution to finish and capture the error code...
- check for success instead of failure?  (if it didn't succeed you know it failed right?), this may be evident based on what the Cypher does, or you could add a graph content update for this purpose.  E.g. Update property on a NODE with last_updated.  Do that last so that if the cypher fails, the property is not updated
- You could enable query log and then check there to see what happened, most likely this query has a unique signature and the last execution could be found easily in the log (with status/error code)